# "spring-integration-2.0.xsd" error when specifying supporting XSDs for int-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, xsd, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have a functional Spring Integration context configuration file.  I want to add jdbc functionality.  When I import the XML namespaces I end up getting an error that seems to be coming from the framework.  The configuration below works properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

This configuration will cause an exception (even though I referenced the contents right from the [examples Github project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/jdbc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

The exception is:  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfE3T.png)
[image]

Here are the versions I'm using:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring.integration.version>2.2.4.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
```

edit: adding just jdbc (and not int-jdbc) also is fine.  The problem arises when adding both.

edit2: I don't get the error until I try to use `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>...`

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's just a validation error from your IDE.
You can solve it with Spring support for it (e.g. IDEA or STS).

From other side what is the reason to use so old Spring and Spring Integration version?

http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration

Comment: I'm using STS.  Should I ignore or turn off those validations?  I'm using those versions because (I'm told) those are what are currently supported for enterprise use.  My pom must conform to the same versions as used in other projects on my team.

Comment: IF your app just works, you should disable validation for that warn. We don't support 2.2.x line already

Answer (score 0):

Oversight on my part.  This was not in the pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
</dependency>
```